# R cannot export all rows to csv

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

Fundamental stuff but i couldn't seem to get around this. I performed the following process:

```
d1<-read.csv('hourly.csv',sep=",",header=F)
names(d1)<-c("date","rain","q","qa","qb")
d2<-read.csv('event.csv',sep=",",header=F)
names(d2)<-c("enum","st","et","rain2","qtot")

for(k in 1:206){
st<-d2[k,2]
et<-d2[k,3]
Datetime<-d1[st,]

print(Datetime)
write.csv(Datetime, file="DatesA3.csv")
}
```

In the end, i exported the results to a csv file. There are 206 rows altogether and they display fine in R. But when exporting, only the last row is exported in the csv file. I tried multiple things such at write.table, append, etc. but nothing seems to work.

How do i export every row into one file?
Please advise and thank you!

Comment: put `write.csv()` outside the loop. Also `Datetime` can't possibly have 206 rows. It'll only have data from the last loop run.

Answer (score 1):

```
Datetime[k, ] <- d1[st, ] # instead, otherwise you overwrite
# and write the result outside the loop
```

Comment: This worked!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Simple help by a good samaritan like this is so helpful. Much better than those who only police questions being asked down-voted but provide no real help. These are real problems faced by others too. After extensive googling and searching here, I just couldn't find this being asked before!

Comment: I'm quite sure it's been asked before but unless you already could describe the logical error, I cannot imagine how you would have found it. I do searches for duplicates using the terms that the questioner asks. If I can find one, then I mark as duplicate and perhaps downvote, but that was clearly not appropriate here. As I migrate from a Mac to Ubuntu, I'm getting much more sympathetic to new R users like yourself.